# Get Body Tag Style Attribute Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string of HTML code stored in a variable

```
var contents = "<html><body style='background-color:red; background-attachment:fixed; margin:20px; display:block; background-size:cover;'></body></html>"
```

How can I get the content within the style attribute, or any other attribute in the body tag?

EDIT: for the answers below the html and body tags are removed when converting string into elements. Sorry I just realized this and it would actually need to get it from the plain string.

Comment: this is not pure JS syntax . Elaborate on what you tried.

Comment: Forgot to include the jQuery tag, sorry. I simply want to get the styles within the "style" attribute in the body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DOMParser();

```
var htmlString = "<html><body style='background-color:red; background-attachment:fixed; margin:20px; display:block; background-size:cover;'><p>test</p></body></html>"

var dp = new DOMParser();
var context = dp.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

var $contextBody = $(context).find('body');
console.log($contextBody.attr('style'));
```

DOMParser is supported in modern browsers but you should check here for compatibility. 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=xml-serializer

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you could try;

```
var css = $(body).prop('css');
```

or if you're not;

```
var css = document.body.getAttribute('css');
```

### Edit

Ah, if you're looking to get it from your variable, that's slightly different. You might have some success with (untested);

```
var css = contentsHTML.find('body').prop('css');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [**DOMParser**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) :

```js
var parser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = parser.parseFromString(contents, "text/html"),
    style = doc.querySelector('body').getAttribute('style');

console.log(style);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/a2hua4ju/**

jQuery strips certain tags out, and injecting the sample string (or the like, guess that is only for demonstration purposes) to the DOM is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:
1-

```
var style = $('body').prop('style');
```

to get an object of type: CSS2Properties.

2-

```
var style = $('body').attr('style');
```

to get a string with all the contents of `style` attribute.